# How to delete a Sify Mail account

Tags: account-management, delete

I have created a [Sify Mail](http://mail.sify.com/) account but now I want to delete it. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send a request email to `customercare@sify.com` to de-activate / delete your account